# ¿Cómo hago para que una función me muestre una vista en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

Tengo esta función, esta función me manda a la vista del (curso1) ¿Cómo hago para que esta misma función me mande a (curso2) (curso3)?
esta es la función:

```
<script>
   $("#curso1").hide();

   function curso(valor) {

      console.log(valor)
      if (valor == 1) {
         $("#cursospopulares").hide();
         $("#curso1").show();


      }
   }

   function volver(valor) {

      console.log(valor)
      if (valor == 1) {
         $("#cursospopulares").show();
         $("#curso1").hide();


      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Muchachos, no le pongan negativos, explíquenle por qué está mal enfocada la pregunta y ya. Todos aprendemos :)

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. La función muestra u oculta elementos en un HTML dependiendo del atributo `id` que tienen. No sabemos cuándo se ejecuta `curso(x)` o `volver(y)` porque no incluiste el HTML al que le aplicas este script. Tampoco es claro qué intentaste para lograr lo que preguntas. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: es que no me dejar agregar mas codigo, lo que necesito es que esa function me muestre tambien la  otra vista que la tengo llamada como "curso2"

Answer (score 2):

A pesar que la pregunta no tiene mucho sentido, esta bien dar un ejemplo.

```js
  // $("#curso1").hide(); Se omite por el CSS

   function curso(valor) {
          
          $(".c").hide(); //oculto todo
      console.log(valor)
        //if (valor == 1) { omuto el if
         $("#cursospopulares").hide();
         $("#curso"+valor).show(); // agrego el valor para que muestre el curso por el
         //} omuto el if
   }
```

```css
.hide{
display:none;
}
.c{
margin:20px;
  height:100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color:green;
}
.c1{
  background-color:red;
}
.c2{
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn btn-info" onClick="curso(1)">ver Curso 1</div>
<div class="btn btn-info" onClick="curso(2)">ver Curso 2</div>
<div class="btn btn-info" onClick="curso(3)">ver Curso 3</div>

<div id="curso1" class="c hide"></div>
<div id="curso2" class="c c1 hide"></div>
<div id="curso3" class="c c2 hide"></div>
```